# Como podria descargar varias imagenes por separado y no en zip

Tags: php

Estoy programando una aplicacion donde intento descargar varias imagenes de una BD, lo he programado en base a que si es 1 se descargue solo esa y si son varias se descargue un zip con todas. Pero me gustaria que se pudiesen descargar sin estar comprimidas. Os dejo el codigo de esa parte y agradezco cualquier ayuda o consejo:

```
//Creo un directorio para la imagen 
if (!is_dir("directorio")) {
    mkdir("directorio");
}

// Abrir el Zip recuperado de la API
// Si tine un solo archivo de imagen, descarga una imagen; si tiene varios arcivos desacarga el ZIP
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$pathZip = $id_tienda.'.zip';
if ($zip->open($pathZip) === TRUE) {
    if ($zip->numFiles == 1) {
        // si e zip solo tine una foto
        $filename = $zip->getNameIndex(0);
        $zip->extractTo("directorio");

        // forzar la descarga del archivo de foto con cabezeras
        $path = "directorio/".$filename;
        if (is_file($path)) { 
            $size = filesize($path); 
            if (function_exists('mime_content_type')) { 
            $type = mime_content_type($path); 
            } else if (function_exists('finfo_file')) { 
                echo "hola else if";
            $info = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME); 
            $type = finfo_file($info, $path); 

            finfo_close($info); 

            }   
        } 


        $archivoSinEspacios = str_replace(' ', '_', $filename);
        header('Content-Type: "'.$type.'"'); 
        header('Content-Length: '.$size); 
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"'); 
        readfile($path);
        unlink($path); // elimina el archivo imagen del servidor


    } else if ($zip->numFiles >= 2) {
        // si tiene más de un archivo, descargar el zip

        // forzar la descarga del zip con cabezeras
        $archivoSinEspacios = str_replace(' ', '_', $pathZip);
        header("Content-type: application/zip");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$archivoSinEspacios);

        // leemos el archivo creado para descarga
        readfile($pathZip);
    }

}   
$zip->close();
unlink($pathZip); // elimina el archivo zip del servidor
```

Answer (score 0):

HTTP no permite el envío de múltiples archivo.
Lo que sí puedes hacer, es por medio de ayuda de Javascript, hacer varias peticiones a la vez, una por cada archivo.

Esto lo puedes hacer mediante:

- ajax / XMLHttpRequest (lo más recomendable)
- un tab por cada archivo (puede verse bloqueado por el browser y/o algún plugin)
- iframe (la peor solución)